# how to design progress bar similar to range bar in mobiles

Tags: javascript, html

i need to design  progress bar using html and javascript that is similar to signal strength indicators in mobiles. the bar should be adjustable like a slider. some of the music players have this type of bar.The slider values will be available dynamically and I need to show the slider accordingly.can anyone please help me in how to achieve this.